# Specify Android SDK used by flutter

Tags: android, flutter

I installed Android SDK 28 using Android Studio.

`flutter doctor` returns

```
[√] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 28.0.3)
```

My `build.gradle` only references SDK 28

```
compileSdkVersion 28

minSdkVersion 28
targetSdkVersion 28
```

However when I execute `flutter build apk` it always starts with

```
Preparing "Install Android SDK Platform 27 (revision: 3)".
```

And then it fails during the build because some dependencies requires the SDK 28.

Is there another configuration to make flutter use the right SDK ?

Comment: Are you using libraries that depend on native code ? or is it a blank project?

Comment: I use flutter_blue, system_setting and shared_preferences, I guess all of them use native code.

Comment: One of that libraries might use a different sdk to compile. Use the latest versions and if that doesn't work remove all the libraries from pubspec.yaml and comment the code that references to it. Then check if it compiles. If it does. Enable the libraries one by one until it doesn't compile. That should be the problematic one

Comment: Thank you, the problem was system_setting, the library was updated on Github but not released!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Credit to @ValdaXD for the answer

> One of that libraries might use a different sdk to compile. Use the latest versions and if that doesn't work remove all the libraries from pubspec.yaml and comment the code that references to it. Then check if it compiles. If it does. Enable the libraries one by one until it doesn't compile. That should be the problematic one